# Why does Tucker Carlson (an American) say "A man called" rather than "A man named"?

Tags: american-english

Tucker Carlson is an American FOX news anchor. He's from San Francisco CA originally.

However he constantly uses the non-American (British) expression

**A man called...**

rather than

**A man named...**

What could explain this? Example: https://youtu.be/mi-_VqYODLw?t=292

Comment: I assume because it’s just another small way he can insult the person.  You’d have to go back through all his reporting over the last five years and see how names those people he supports.

Comment: He refers to everyone using this expression. Hence the question. It's not a matter of personal attitude.

Comment: Well, I've learnt something. I had no idea that Americans don't use "a man called". Looking at the GloWbE corpus, I see that US sources have 588:100 (named:called), whereas they're almost equal (390:388) in GB sources. Canada is even more extreme (173:23), Australia somewhere in the middle (154:85) and NZ almost equal (75:71)

Comment: @ColinFine I have never in my life heard any American say "a man called..." Tucker Carlson is the only example. I'm 40 years old.

Comment: @geneb. I'm older than you and I hear it all the time. It's also pretty well represented in popular culture. Cf. [A Man Called Horse](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0066049/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1) (film), [A Man Called Ove](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt7405458/), (film), etc.

Comment: @Jim was right, though. It's an insult. It's just that he insults everybody. It makes him look strong to some people. Those are his fans.

Comment: @Robusto - And that’s ok when there’s a difference between what you’re called (e.g. a nickname) and what you’re named.  But when someone says you’re “called” your actual name, that comes off as a little sarcastic.

Comment: It could be a regional or family thing. His father was also a reporter, did he use this phrase?

Comment: That's my impression, that it's a CA thing of some kind, which doesn't conform to general English. Similar to how in CA people use the "aw" sound rather than "ah" in words like "college." But I could be wrong.

Answer (score 3):

I don’t see an insult here, maybe a little sarcasm. Tucker is a commentator, not a reporter. Rush Limbaugh used to say “schedule” the British way just to entertain his listeners. There isn’t much to it. I’d be surprised if English TV hosts did not use “rustic” American pronunciation the same way.

There is a possible nuance here also. You are named at birth but called something else. A man named O’Shea Jackson is the man called (and known as) Ice Cube.

Comment: He legally changed his name to Ice Cube. So he *was* named O'Shea Jackson, but he *is* named Ice Cube now.

Comment: And the person Tucker Carlson was talking about doesn't seem to be using a pseudonym.

Comment: I wasn't aware of any insult either, but the establishment gets awfully defensive whenever a challenge arises -- even when all someone does is talk.

Comment: @Barmar. Thanks bro. Ice Cube all the way.

Comment: DeaAnna Price, an American athlete, found her performance flagging in 2015, but, as she said "fortunately I met a man called Brian Murer (a chiropractor)".